# Redmine REST API called from Ruby is ignoring updates to some fields

Tags: rest, redmine

I have some code which was working at one point but no longer works, which strongly suggests that the redmine configuration is involved somehow (I'm not the redmine admin), but the lack of any error messages makes it hard to determine what is wrong.  Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
gem "activeresource", "2.3.14"
require "active_resource"

class Issue < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "https://redmine.mydomain.com/"
end

Issue.user = "myname"
Issue.password = "mypassword"  # Don't hard-code real passwords :-)

issue = Issue.find 19342  # Created manually to avoid messing up real tickets.
field = issue.custom_fields.select { |x| x.name == "Release Number" }.first
issue.notes = "Testing at #{Time.now}"
issue.custom_field_values = { field.id => "Release-1.2.3" }
success = issue.save
puts "field.id: #{field.id}"
puts "success: #{success}"
puts "errors: #{issue.errors.full_messages}"
```

When this runs, the output is:

```
field.id: 40
success: true
errors: []
```

So far so good, except that when I go back to the GUI and look at this ticket, the "notes" part is updated correctly but the custom field is unchanged.  I did put some tracing in the ActiveRecord code and that appears to be sending out my desired updates, so I suspect the problem is on the server side.

BTW if you know of any good collections of examples of accessing Redmine from Ruby using the REST API that would be really helpful too.  I may just be looking in the wrong places, but all I've found are a few trivial ones that are just enough to whet one's appetite for more, and the docs I've seen on the redmine site don't even list all the available fields.  (Ideally, it would be nice if the examples also specified which version of redmine they work with.)

Comment: I have the same issue except that I am experiencing this on the /time_entries.xml
Monitoring the HTTP traffic I see that I the correct HTTP request is sent and I get the 200 OK from the service, but I see no changes to the comments field of the time entry.

Comment: Can you show us the body of the request that gets sent?